# How to set Click NavigationItem menu in Android

Tags: android, android-menu, navigation-drawer

I want use `NavidationDrawer` for application menu, but when click on `NavigationItems` not action! I want when click on `NavigationItems`, start other `Activities`.
**Main XML :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/backgroundPrimary"
        tools:context="com.tellfa.dastanak.Activities.MainActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_appBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

                <com.tellfa.dastanak.Components.CodeSaz_TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/textLight"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/tabIndicatorColor" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/main_viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/menu_header"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_main_page" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Main code :**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private DataBase dataBase;
    private Cat1_frag_AsyncTask task;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dataBase = new DataBase(this);
        try {
            dataBase.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        TextView toolbar_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
        toolbar_text.setText(R.string.app_name_fa);
        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("");
        actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu_driver);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        if (navigationView != null) {
            setupDrawerContent(navigationView);
        }

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.main_viewPager);
        if (viewPager != null) {
            setupViewPager(viewPager);
        }

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_tabs);
        if (tabLayout != null) {
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_page, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            case R.id.action_recyclerView:
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Recycler_Page.class));
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_recyclerView:
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Recycler_Page.class));
        }
        return onNavigationItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        Main_frag_adapter mainFragAdapter = new Main_frag_adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mainFragAdapter.addFragment(new Cat1_fragment_recycler(), "آموزنده");
        mainFragAdapter.addFragment(new Cat2_fragment_recycler(), "عاشقانه");
        mainFragAdapter.addFragment(new Cat3_fragment_recycler(), "بزرگان");
        mainFragAdapter.addFragment(new Cat4_fragment_recycler(), "متفرقه");

        viewPager.setAdapter(mainFragAdapter);
    }

    private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        menuItem.setChecked(true);
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        return true;
                    }
                });
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    private void forceRTLIfSupported() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
        }
    }
}
```

How can i it? tnx <3

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

put this line

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Recycler_Page.class));
```

in

```
private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView)
```

so updated method is like:

```
 private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        menuItem.setChecked(true);
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Recycler_Page.class));                        
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        return true;
                    }
                });
}
```